# Drag and Drop into Document Library via Page Webpart

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, drag-and-drop

I've created a Document Library that I can drag and drop documents into.
Then I added that Document Library as a webpart on a 3 column page.

I am able to drag and drop in if the page is checked-out. But when I publish tha page I can't drag and drop documents into the library webpart anymore.

Any ideas how to fix this? Or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using **SharePoint 2013** latest version and **IE 10**.

Answer (score 3):

Add below script
​​

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.Utilities.Utility',uploadedFunc);
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.core.js','SP.Utilities.CommandBlock', uploadedFunc);
function uploadedFunc()
{
alert("uploaded");
}
</script>​
```

The `SP.Utilities.CommandBlock` does not get loaded on View mode of page.